# What is the algebraic normal form of $F(x,y,z)= Trace (\alpha x^{24}) + x^{312} + yz$?

Tags: finite-fields, cryptography

Let $w$ be a primitive element of $\mathbb F_{5^4}$. Let $\alpha=w^{13}$. Define,
    $F:\mathbb F_{5^4}\times \mathbb F_{5}\times \mathbb F_{5} \Rightarrow  \mathbb F_{5} $ as,
$$F(x,y,z)= Tr (\alpha x^{24}) + x^{312} + yz,$$

where Tr is the trace function from $\mathbb F_{5^4}$ to $F_{5}$ defined as $Tr(x)=x+x^5+x^{25}+x^{125}$.

What is the algebraic norm (ANF) of $F$?

Comment: What is *algebraic normal form*? I may have heard of the concept at some point, but at the moment I'm lost :-)

Comment: We can regard $\mathbb F_{5^4}$ as the 4-dimensional vector space $\mathbb F_5^4$ over $\mathbb F_5$. Then, we can redefine the function $F$ from $\mathbb F_5^6$ to $\mathbb F_5$ and represent it as a polynomial with the form $$f(x)=\sum_{I \in P(N)}a_Ix^I,$$ where $P(N)$ denotes power set of $N=\left\{1,\cdots,6\right\}$ and $a_I \in \mathbb F_5$

Comment: I mean, it is simply the new representation of $F$ when it is defined from $\mathbb F_5^6$ to $\mathbb F_5$. $$F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,y,z)=?$$

Comment: Ok. Won't that depend on the choice of basis of $\Bbb{F}_{625}$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{F}_5$ though? Also probably on the choice of a primitive element $w$.

Comment: ANF is unique for $\mathbb F_2$ but I do not know actually it is true or not for $\mathbb F_5$. There is an example for $\mathbb F_2$ here, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109296/finding-boolean-logical-expressions-for-truth-tables-in-algebraic-normal-forman However, $\mathbb F_{5^6}$ is too large to apply this method..

Comment: I doubt it is unique even over $\Bbb{F}_2$. Surely it depends on the choice of basis! For example the boolean function OR as a mapping from $\Bbb{F}_2^2\to\Bbb{F}_2$ takes the form $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$ w.r.t. the first basis that comes to the mind. But w.r.t. another basis it might become $g(x_1,x_2)=f(x_1,x_1+x_2=x_1+x_1x_2)$. In the Karnaugh-map setting the basis is fixed by fixing the variables. Here I don't see such a preferred basis.